# pg_dump custom format

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I wish I could experiment around `pg_dump`’s “custom” format.

Is there any documentation available for this format? Or any library to help read/write such files?

Comment: The format is documented in the source code.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe, the source code certainly is the most accurate and up-to-date documentation one could dream of. I hoped there might be something more human-friendly but I had a look at the source code and it’s pretty readable. Thanks!